# SUM(COUNTIF[multiple]) = 0?

Tags: excel, vba

What is causing the below code to return zeros?

```
        Sheet1.Range("e2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsR.Range("D2:D" & LastRowD), "[string1]", _
                                                                                    wsR.Range("D2:D" & LastRowD), "[string2]", _
                                                                                    wsR.Range("D2:D" & LastRowD), "[string3]", _
                                                                                    wsR.Range("D2:D" & LastRowD), "[string4]"))
```

I have read numerous threads, doubled parenthesis', `""[string#]""` and found what seems to be more elegant code but VBA rejects enclosed `{}` brackets. The alternative (preferred) syntax expression is:

```
        Sheet1.Range("e2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsR.Range("D2:D" & LastRowD), {"[string1]","[string2]","[string3]","[string4]"}))
```

Hoping for some clarification on what I am missing.

**EDIT**

```
 Dim criteriaRng As Range
 Set criteriaRng = wsR.Range("D2:D" & LastRowD)
 
Dim myFormula As String
myFormula = "SUM(COUNTIFS(criteriaRng,{""[string1]"",""[string2]"",""[string3]"",""[string4]""}))"
Sheet1.Range("E2").Value = wsR.Evaluate(myFormula)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` with an array of criteria (someone may correct me though).

In any case, you should be able to use `Evaluate`:

```
Dim criteriaRng as Range
Set criteriaRng = wsR.Range("D2:D" & LastRowD)

Dim myFormula as String
myFormula = "SUM(COUNTIFS(" & rng.Address & "," & _
                 "{""string1"",""string2"",""string3"",""string4""}))"

Sheet1.Range("E2").Value = wsR.Evaluate(myFormula)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Big Ben. Tried some syntax independently and then found you had provided an example. VBA threw a few errors and I modified it accordingly (see EDIT in Q), though it returns #NAME? now. Is it missing quotation marks?

Comment: See how my answer concatenates `rng.Address` using `&`, while yours has `criteriaRng` falling within the quotes? That's the issue. Variables don't belong inside the quotes; VBA doesn't do variable expansion. Plus you should use the `.Address`.

Comment: Many thanks, @Big Ben. I had naively removed the "" and concatenating & because of the encasing variables issue. Not sure what variable expansion is (yet) but Evaluate will become a staple of my coding going forward!

Comment: The takeaway of my comment is that variables don't belong inside quotes. `Evaluate` is quite useful though, yes!

Answer (score 0):

The first formula counts number of entries that contains *ALL* of [stringX] (X=1,2,3,4). Is that what you really want?

If you want an "OR" criteria, you may use the following array function:

```
Sheet1.Range("e2").FormulaArray = "=COUNT(FIND(D2:D" & LastRowD & ",""[string1][string2][string3][string4]""))"
```

assuming 1) "[stringX]" are not substring in column D, and 2) [stringX] are not substring of each other.